# Python Selenium fill out dynamic popup

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, iframe

I am very new to Selenium and trying to iterate over a couple firms on this website: https://www.msci.com/our-solutions/esg-investing/esg-ratings-climate-search-tool

However, after a few searches a popup appears that has to be filled out before one can continue (see picture).

[image]

I would like to fill it out and continue with my search. I have tried **switch_to.frame()**, but it did not work.

Here is my code so far and I would like to add that I can fill out the iframe and press submit:

```
for comp in companies:
    driver.get('https://www.msci.com/our-solutions/esg-investing/esg-ratings-climate-search-tool')
    element = driver.find_element(By.ID, '_esgratingsprofile_keywords')
    element.send_keys(comp)
    
    try:
        # wait for the first dropdown option to appear and open it
        first_option = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'ui-id-1')))
        element.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
        element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    
        # wait for the next dropdowns
        second_option = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'esg-transparency-toggle-link')))
        second_option.click()
    
        # extract the data

        name = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "header-company-title"))).text
        industry = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "header-esg-industry"))).text
        

        comp_score = {
        'name': name,
        'industry': industry,
        }
        
    except:
        comp_score = {
        'name': comp,
        'industry': 'NA',
        }
```

Where *companies* is a lift of a few company names covered by the website.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you need to switch to `iframe` and then insert the value in the following field.
Once done that and submit the pop up,  you need to switch back from `iframe`

Use below code where you think you are getting that popup

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#_esgratingsprofile_subscriptionFormPopup_iframe_")))
    WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input#_esgratingsprofile_firstName"))).send_keys("vossi")
    #add rest of the code

    #end switch back from iframe
    driver.switch_to.default_content()

except:
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you. This is basically what I tried before. I used your code, as well, but  for some reason it does not switch to the popup or does not manage to send the keys to the popup... I do not understand why